# Was the Wright Brothers' 1902 machine a working glider or just a kite?

Tags: aviation-history, stability, aircraft-physics

Was the Wright Brothers' 1902 machine a working glider or just a kite?

---

I spent the last days reading the letters and articles of Amos I. Root, the man who claimed he had seen Wilbur Wright flying his plane in a circuit on September 20, 1904.

I had already been aware that the 1903-1905 powered flights of the Wright brothers could be a fraud but I was convinced, before reading the above mentioned book, that the 1902 machine was a true glider that could be flown in a stable manner for 600 feet.

From what I have found on the internet (see the two attached videos) it appears that the 1902 glider could be more a kite. I simply do not find videos with this apparatus in free flight for distances like 100-200 meters or even shorter.

**Question**: Have somebody built a replica, of the 1902 apparatus, that flew without being towed and kept stable by people on the ground?

---

[image: The letters of Amos Root to the Wright brothers and his articles about them]
*The letters of Amos Root to the Wright brothers and his articles about them.*
[Click to download the book.](http://wright-brothers.wikidot.com/)

[image: A replica of the 1902 Wright glider]
*A replica of the 1902 Wright glider.*
[Click for the video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eigdBanBW8w)

[image: A replica of the 1896 Chanute Herring Glider]
*A replica of the 1896 Chanute Herring glider.*
[Click for the video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWCrsDK-wc0)

The 1896 Chanute-Herring machine is a real glider, as ca be see from the video. It does not fly long distances but its stability is remarkable.

Comment: The Wright brothers are [first by contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_by_Contract) anyway. This makes things a lot more simple.

Comment: It worked, but it did not have good performance, so they flew it as a kite instead.